# Linux Console / standard out save by default

Tags: linux, console, stdout

I have been attempting to find an answer for the following question everywhere:

Does the standard output / console on linux save the contents to a file by default?

I am not looking to save the contents or redirect the output (i already know about that), i am just wondering if it happens already by some default process included with linux and ran by root. Finding an answer has been difficult due to all the redirection questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unix based systems won't save the console outputs anywhere by default.

As you may know, hardware terminals (tty) and pseudo-terminals (pty) are just ways for a process to cast bytes, but it seems there is no system process that catches and log these casts.

[What is stored in /dev/pts files and can we open them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93531/what-is-stored-in-dev-pts-files-and-can-we-open-them)